# CakePHP 1.3 - Calling Shells from a Controller?

Tags: shell, cakephp, controller, cakephp-1.3

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to call a shell from a controller.

We have a background process that packages up data in a .pdf, and we don't want to bog down the page loads waiting for this to occur, so we want to put all this processing in a shell.

I've figured out how to pass values to a shell with $this->args

I know you can use App::import('Shell','TestShell')... but after that I am lost.

How do I call the main() function of the shell within a controller?

Comment: Wanting to run a shell from a controller is a typically a very clear indicator of model code (which can be called by both a controller and shell) _not_ being in a model.

Answer (score 2):

In Cake 1.3, I was able to get it working by doing the following:

```
App::import('Shell', 'Shell');
App::Import('Vendor', array('shells/shell_title'));

$myShell = new ShellTitleShell(new Object());
$myShell->initialize();
$myShell->someAction();
```

Answer (score -1):

I should be more focused reading the question :/

Could do it in Cake2, not sure how different would it be for 1.3. :?

```
<?php
App::import('Console/Command', 'AppShell');
App::import('Console/Command', 'HelloWorldShell');
$h = new HelloWorldShell();
$h->dispatchMethod('main');
?>
```

**Windows**: 
If you do not have your environment variables set you will need to provide location of  PHP executable.

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php_v\php.exe C:\wamp\www\cakephp\cake\console\cake.php test this_arg_0 this_arg_1
```

**Linux**:
You may already have your php location defined. If not, you may need to export it to your $PATH or provide full path to php

```
php /var/www/html/cakephp/cake/console/cake.php test this_arg_0 this_arg_1
```

main() function will be called by default.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Those are weird cli usage examples -1

Comment: How is that weird? Its just absolute paths in case you don't have those path defined.

Comment: Well, the question isn't about cli usage at all, much less cli usage in a borked environment. So compared to `cd /var/www/html/cakephp/app; ../cake/console/cake test ...` - these examples are plain weird. If php isn't in the path - that's not normal, and something to fix not work around.